# How to use generics for variable?

Tags: java, generics

I have the following:

```
public class Helper {
    public void doSomething(List<? extends MyClass> p1, Collection<? extends MyClass> c1) {
        final <? extends MyClass> var1 = p1.get(0); // what should be here for the type ?
    }
}
```

How can I make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you pretend to do with an "instance of" `<? extends MyClass`?. Either you treat it as a `MyClass` instance, or you check if it's an instance of an appropiate subclass of `MyClass` with `instanceof`. Anything else just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ninjalj Yes it make sense, I would to insert var1 in c1. If I don't use the generics, the code won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned elsewhere you can simply type the variable as MyClass, or you could write your code with reference to generic T like this

```
public class Helper {
    public <T extends MyClass> void doSomething(List<T> p1, Collection<T> c1) {
        final T var1 = p1.get(0); 
    }
}
```

Comment: only if he intended to require the type parameters of `p1` and `c1` to be the same

Answer (score 3):

The following should be correct:

```
final MyClass var1 = p1.get(0);
```